# Nvim-cmp is adding multiple times the same sources

Tags: lua, config, neovim

I'm using `nvim-cmp`to have a contextual window to display my LSP suggestions and my snippets but when I open multiple buffers, I have an issue : the same source is added multiple times to `nvim-cmp` causing the same result to be repeated in the popup.

For example, here is the result of `:CmpStatus`: after a few minutes of work.

```lua
# ready source names
- vsnip
- buffer
- nvim_lsp:pylsp
- vsnip
- nvim_lsp:pylsp
- nvim_lsp:pylsp
```

Here is my `nvim-cmp`config :

```lua
cmp.setup({
    snippet = {
        expand = function(args)
            vim.fn["vsnip#anonymous"](args.body)
        end,
    },
    ...
    sources = {
        { name = 'vsnip' },
        { name = 'nvim_lua' },
        { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
        { name = 'buffer', keyword_length = 3 }
    },
}
```

Does anyone know how to adress this issue ? Is it a problem with my configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

In your cmp configuration, you can use the `dup` keyword for `vim_item` with the `formatting` option / `format` function. See help for `complete-item` for explanations (`:help complete-item`).

```lua
cmp.setup({
  formatting = {
    format = function(entry, vim_item)
      vim_item.menu = ({
        nvim_lsp = '[LSP]',
        vsnip = '[Snippet]',
        nvim_lua = '[Nvim Lua]',
        buffer = '[Buffer]',
      })[entry.source.name]

      vim_item.dup = ({
        vsnip = 0,
        nvim_lsp = 0,
        nvim_lua = 0,
        buffer = 0,
      })[entry.source.name] or 0

      return vim_item
    end
  }
})
```

You can see details in this [feature request](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/issues/511) for `nvim-cmp` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even after adding the dup config, I keep having the same source added multiple times when I open new buffers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve the issue by realizing that cmp is somehow installed twice.

Try removing or better first renaming the cmp-packages in the plugged directory, for example

`cmp-nvim-lsp` to `cmp-nvim-lsp_not`

`cml-nvim-buffer` to `cmp-nvim-buffer_not`
etc.

This did the job for me.